# Weird occurrence happening when comparing two list (groovy)

Tags: java, list, grails, groovy, compare

I am trying to scan one lists contents if the other list also contains a similar item.

I am also not sure if this is the most effective way to go through the list from what I am currently using.

Code below that I'm trying to run:

```
List list1 = [["GNCSSTDI", "Joe", "Thu Mar 07 19:43:59 EST 2019", "Logged work on 3/7"], ["LMGQYNQU", "Joe", "Thu Mar 07 21:41:50 EST 2019", "logged 3/7"]]

List list2 = ["GNCSSTDI", "LMGQYNQU", "AEIOSJWP"]

list1.each { l1 ->
    list2.each { l2 ->
        if (list1.toString() == l2.toString())
        {
            // match found
            log.debug("MATCH FOUND")
        }
    }
}
```

It never iterates to that for loop? What exactly am I doing wrong. The first item from each list should have matched if I'm not mistaken?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*list1* is `list` of lists. So, you should iterate each item again after fetching from *list1*

```
list1.each { l1 ->
    l1.each { subL1 ->
        list2.each { l2 ->
            if (subL1.toString() == l2.toString()) {
                // match found
                println "match found"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: lol overlooked that bad..... so that explains also why when i did get it work it kept returning true every iteration. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do with the results, something like this may be useful;

```
List matches = list1*.intersect(list2).flatten()
```

The result of your example would be: [GNCSSTDI, LMGQYNQU]